# Google Map title appears when click on marker,but immediately gets disappears android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have implemented Google map in my android application,in which I want when app launches the current location get visible with marker on it,and when click on marker the title should be displayed.But what happening is,title appears and immediately gets disappears.I have used showInfoWindow() but it shows title even when i scroll on map,which i don't want.I have also tried hideInfoWindow(), marker click listener and info window click listener,but not able to find any solution.When i debug the code,the debugger goes to marker click listener,shows marker and immediately comes to onCameraIdle(), last conditions where marker is setting. Below is my code for onMapReady(),onCameraIdle(). Please help me,to find out solution.

MapFragment.java:-

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
if (Constants.isNetworkAvailable(MapsFragmentActivity.this)) {
mMap = googleMap;
mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);
mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
return;
}
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
handleIntent(getIntent());
}
}
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
if (Constants.isNetworkAvailable(MapsFragmentActivity.this)) {
if (marker != null) {
marker.remove();
}
if (CameraLat == 0.0 && CameraLong == 0.0) {
CameraLat = mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
CameraLong = mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
}
Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Log.i("LOcation", "location--->" + location);

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
Log.i("LOcation", "latLng--->" + latLng);
if (location.getLatitude() != 0.0 && location.getLongitude() != 0.0 ) {
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// TODO: Consider calling
return;
}
try {
if(!filterAddress.isEmpty()){
filterAddress="";
}
// if(location!=null) {
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0)
.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
if (addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) != null) {
filterAddress += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i)
+ " ";
}
}
markerOptions.position(latLng);
markerOptions.title(filterAddress);
marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

Log.i("LOcation", "filterAddress--->" + filterAddress);

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}else{
Constants.alert("No internet connection",MapsFragmentActivity.this);
}
}
```

Comment: Would you please indent your code properly?

Comment: Would you please read questions posted by other people to see what is meant by indenting "properly"? You may press the "edit" link on other posts to see the original text posted by the author.

Comment: Oh sorry,@SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji-

Comment: Never mind~ I'm here just to help new comers to post their questions properly.

Comment: Have you tried moving `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);` from your `onCameraIdle()` method to your `onMapReady()` method?